# C++ linker error when access to static member in nested class

Tags: c++, static, nested

GCC 4.8 can't compile following code:

```
struct A {
  struct Impl;
  void f();
};

struct A::Impl {
  static int stat;
};

void A::f(){
  A::Impl::stat=1;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
return 0;
}
```

and raise error:

> cppbug.cpp:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `A::Impl::stat'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

but similar inline declaraton compiled as well:

```
struct A {
  struct Impl {
    static int stat;
  };

  void f(){
    A::Impl::stat=1;
  }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your second version has the same problem, as soon you're going to create an instance for `A` and call `f()`. See here please: http://ideone.com/fwVEAb

Comment: Interesting. I have GCC 4.8.2 and second example was linked. But ideone.com have GCC 4.8.1 and it didn't.